# Directive Isolate Scope 1.2.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working with Angular version 1.2.2 for the first time and trying to make a simple directive that uses isolate scope with '=' binding to pass in an object. I've done this a few times before so I'm wondering if maybe there was a change in 1.2.2 that changed this?

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('vendorSelector', function (VendorFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { vendorId: '=' },
        template:   '<select ng-model="vendorId" ng-options="id for id in vendorIds">' +
                        '<option value="">-- choose vendor --</option>' +
                    '</select>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            VendorFactory.getVendorIds().then(function(result) {
                scope.vendorIds = result;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

My HTML template using the directive is as follows:

```
<div class="padding">
    <vendor-selector vendorId="someValue"></vendor-selector>
    {{ someValue }}
</div>
```

And the backing controller:

```
.controller('AddProductController', function($scope, ProductFactory, AlertFactory) {
    $scope.vendorId = 0;
    $scope.someValue = undefined;
})
```

I've tried using both $scope.someValue and $scope.vendorId as the supplied object in the html template. In both cases the error I'm getting back is `Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'vendorSelector' is non-assignable!`. Am I missing something obvious that is preventing these values from being 2-way bound in the isolate scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html:

```
<vendor-selector vendorId="someValue"></vendor-selector>
```

Change `vendorId="someValue"`

to `vendor-id="someValue"`

HTML attributes are case insensitive so to avoid confusion Angular converts all camel cased variables (vendorId) to snake case attributes (vendor-id).

So `someValue` wasn't bound to `vendorId`.  Resulting in `vendorId` being undefined in the template.  And thus your error.

Comment: Thank you! You are a gentleman and a scholar. I should have known better as I had appropriately changed the directive name for the camelCase just completely missed the attribute :P

Comment: There have been a bunch of changes in 1.2, including ones related to isolate scope, so I totally relate to your thinking going there.  You're very welcome!

Comment: There have been a ton of changes: Namely, it works! (Doesn't take over the scope of non-isolate directives on the same element.) Also, linking priority is in reverse order.